# Timer for Simple Ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Have a [simple ajax](http://depresionysuicidio.com/demo/demo.html) for loading content into a page.
What I want is for the loaded content to wait a set amount of time before showing on the page. (before the fadeIn)
I tried using jQuery's .delay() function after it fades the #body in but it did not work.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for your time

JS

```
var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

checkURL();
$('ul li a').click(function (e){

        checkURL(this.hash);

});

//filling in the default content
default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

if(hash != lasturl)
{
    lasturl=hash;

    // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
    // fill the pageContent with the default_content

    if(hash=="")
    $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

    else
    loadPage(hash);
}
}


function loadPage(url)
{
url=url.replace('#page','');
$('#body').hide ();
$('#loading').css('visibility','visible');


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_page.php",
    data: 'page='+url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            $('#body').fadeIn( 'slow' );
            $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    }

});

}
```

PHP

```
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the setTimeout Javascript function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#pageContent').html(msg);
    $('#body').fadeIn( 'slow' );
    $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
}, 5000);
```

This will wait 5s für the content to be set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(checkURL(/* value to pass */),250);
```

Please don't quote calls to functions, as what's in a " " will be handled as a string, not a function call.